# Why does RubyGems FasterCSV process [[1,3,5], [2,4,6]].to_csv as "135,246\n"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, rubygems, fastercsv

the following code:

```
[1,3,5].to_csv
  => "1,3,5\n"       # this is good

[[1,3,5], [2,4,6]].to_csv
  => "135,246\n"     # why doesn't it just do it for array of array?
```

but require this instead:

```
data = [[1,3,5], [2,4,6]]
csv_string = FasterCSV.generate do |csv|
  data.each {|a| csv << a}  
end
 => "1,3,5\n2,4,6\n"
```

or shorter:

```
data = [[1,3,5], [2,4,6]]
csv_string = FasterCSV.generate {|csv| data.each {|a| csv << a}}
 => "1,3,5\n2,4,6\n"
```

The question is, when given an array of array, why is `to_csv` not designed to handle it automatically, so that in Rails, we can do

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.csv { render :text => data.to_csv }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[1,3,5], [2,4,6]].each{ |line| puts line.to_csv } isn't so bad.  You could always override Array#to_csv if you wanted.

I suspect FasterCSV's decision to not implement that was because it is hard to be absolutely certain that's what the programmer will want.  What if the input happens to be
[[1], 2, 3, 4] ?  Just looking at the first element of the outer array would make you think that it may be an array of arrays...

Comment: how does `[[1,3,5], [2,4,6]].each{ |line| puts line.to_csv }` work with render?  because you can render once only, i guess you will need to use `s += line.to_csv + "\n"`, or  `(@data.map {|a| a.to_csv}).join("\n")`